# VIM JavaScript Indentation Plugin - Comma first

Tags: javascript, vim, plugins, coding-style, indentation

Is there a Javascript indentation plugin for VIM which can handle comma-first notation?

Example:

```
var o = {
    foo: bar
  , bar: foo
  , cde: efg
}
```

I think Sublime Text has support for this.

Comment: The current JS indent files all date back to a glorious time when such an horrible habit didn't exist. You will probably have to modify an existing one.

Comment: It's not horrible. In fact, I think more than half of node.js modules use this style. The most horrible is where you _don't_ have any style at all.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the [JavaScript Indent](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3081) plugin. It doesn't give me the exact same style you are using, but it's certainly better at handling javascript indentation than plain vim.

Comment: I know that people have written JS indent plugins for vim, but I'm looking for one that can handle that style